# roll, pitch and yaw from Vicon angle

Tags: math, rotation, angle, robotics

I need to compare the relative angle of the wrist between two IMUs with the angle obtain from the Vicon but I have a problem. The relative angle obtained from the two IMUs is in the form 'roll, pitch and yaw' but from the Vicon Cameras I obtained only one absolute angle. In order to obtain the angle from the Vicon, I calculated the forearm plane and the hand plane, then I calculated the normal vectors of these planes and at the end from the two normals I obtain the relative angle between the hand and the forearm planes. How I can obtain three values (roll, pitch, yaw) from the relative Vicon angle in order to compare the two systems?
Thanks a lot for the help:)

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you know and what you want to calculate? As far as I understand, you have two object coordinate systems given as (roll, pitch, yaw) transforms from a base system (the camera system). And you want to find the rotational difference between these two systems? In what system do you want the difference represented? One way is to convert the (roll, pitch, yaw) triplets to quaternions and then use `qdiff = q1^-1 * q2`.

Comment: Hi Nico! I have two imu sensors: one on the palm and one on the forearm. The the palm is represented by the quaternion q1 and the forearm by the quaternion q2. Q2 is the reference and I calculated the relative angle with the expression q_rel = q2^-1*q1. After that, I need to compare this angle to the one obtained from the Vicon cameras. I used 8 markers and I calculated the angle in degrees from the hand plane to the forearm plane using the normals of the planes but in this way I obtained an absolute angle and not 3 values such as roll, pitch and yaw.

Comment: That's because the planes do not define a complete coordinate system. You have to add some more information to get the data you want. What about the other way around - converting the relative quaternion to an angle?